# MySQL Multiplication trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called history with the fields id, g.id, date, value. I want to put a trigger that will update the table when a new row is inserted and divide the number inserted in the value field by 2.
I have been trying for hours with no luck, any help would be appreciated.

for eg, after

```
  INSERT INTO `online_game_shop`.`history` 
  (`id`, `gameID`, `dateofPurchase`, `Value`) 
  VALUES ('1001', '101', '2014-02-22', '10');
```

so the trigger will automatically divide 10 by 2 and update the field with result.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER pointstovalue   
  AFTER INSERT ON history 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN 
  UPDATE  history 
  SET     value = new.value/2
  WHERE   history.id = NEW.id
  END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a *before* insert trigger:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER pointstovalue   
  BEFORE INSERT ON history 
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN 
     set new.value = new.value/2;
  END;
```